# Python for loop that stores image predictions to csv starts quickly but slows down

Tags: python, performance, csv, for-loop, tensorflow

I have a folder with >100,000 images, which I would like to classify using TensorFlow. I wrote a for loop that iterates over each image, returns a confidence score, and stores the predictions to a csv file.

The problem is: The script starts very quickly (approx. 10 images per second for images 1-1000) and gradually slows down with each iteration (only about 1 image per second for images >1000).

For similar slow-down issues of for loops in Python, I read that pre-allocation might be a solution. However, I am writing directly to a csv and not a list so I am unsure how this should help.

Is there any way to ensure consistent speed during the entire loop?

Thank you in advance for any pointer!

Please find my code below, which is based on this tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0):

```
filename = "predictions.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "id;image_name;confidence\n"
f.write(headers)
start = 1
end = 20000

testdata = "C:/files/"

files = list(os.listdir(testdata))
for index in range(start, end+1):
    filename = files[index]

    if not filename.startswith('.'):

        print(str(index) + " - " + str(filename))

        image=testdata+filename
        results = label_image(image, graph, session, input_height=299, input_width=299, input_layer="Mul")

        f.write(str(index) + ";" + str(filename) + ";" + str(results[0]) + "\n")

        print("\n")

f.close()
```

EDIT:

I am loading the graph just once before running the loop.

```
from scripts.label_image import load_graph, label_image, get_session
model_file = "retrained_graph.pb"
graph = load_graph(model_file)
session = get_session(graph)
```

EDIT 2:

This is the code of the label_image function.

```
def label_image(file_name, graph, session, label_file="retrained_labels.txt", input_height=224, input_width=224, input_mean=128, input_std=128, input_layer="input", output_layer="final_result"):
  t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                  input_height=input_height,
                                  input_width=input_width,
                                  input_mean=input_mean,
                                  input_std=input_std)

  input_name = "import/" + input_layer
  output_name = "import/" + output_layer
  input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
  output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

  start = time.time()
  results = session.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                      {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  end=time.time()
  results = np.squeeze(results)

  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(label_file)

  print('\nEvaluation time (1-image): {:.3f}s\n'.format(end-start))
  template = "{} (score={:0.5f})"
  for i in top_k:
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))  
  return results
```

EDIT 3:

This is the code of the read_tensor_from_image_file function.

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=299, input_width=299,
                input_mean=0, input_std=255):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                       name='png_reader')
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
    image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                  name='gif_reader'))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
  else:
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                        name='jpeg_reader')
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  sess = tf.Session()
  result = sess.run(normalized)

  return result
```

EDIT 4:

This is my refactored code, which throws me the error:
*AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'endswith'*

```
def process_image(file_name):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                       name='png_reader')
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
    image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                  name='gif_reader'))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
  else:
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                        name='jpeg_reader')
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  return normalized

filename_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
processed = process_image(filename_placeholder)

def label_image(file_name, graph, session, label_file="tf_files/retrained_labels.txt", input_height=224, input_width=224, input_mean=128, input_std=128, input_layer="input", output_layer="final_result"):
  result = sess.run(processed, feed_dict={filename_placeholder: file_name})  


  input_name = "import/" + input_layer
  output_name = "import/" + output_layer
  input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
  output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);


  start = time.time()
  results = session.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                      {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  end=time.time()
  results = np.squeeze(results)

  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(label_file)

  print('\nEvaluation time (1-image): {:.3f}s\n'.format(end-start))
  template = "{} (score={:0.5f})"
  for i in top_k:
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))  
  return results
```

Comment: Please post the `label_image` code. Without seeing it, I'm just gonna assume that you are repeatedly building the graph in each iteration of the loop which will result in a gradual slowdown.

Comment: Thank you. Does the above EDIT prove your assumption right or wrong?

Comment: Can't quite say yet. Do you call _any_ `tf.something` in your `label_image` function?

Comment: I added EDIT 2.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'd need to see the `read_tensor_from_image_file` function as well. :D

Comment: There you go. ;) Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the `read_tensor_from_image_file` function. This function is called in each iteration of the loop. Within the function you are creating Tensorflow ops. As a rule of thumb, `tf.anything` calls are responsible for *building* the computational graph. They should only ever be called *once* and then ran repeatedly using a `tf.Session`. As it is, you are constantly growing the size of your computational graph with "clones" of the same image processing ops, which slows down execution gradually as your graph grows larger.

You should refactor your code such that the op definitions in `read_tensor_from_image_file` are only executed once, and only do the `sess.run(normalized)` part within the loop. You can use a `tf.placeholder` for the input (file name). Also, you shouldn't create a new session each time the function is called -- instead pass through the session from `label_image`.

Here is a reduced example of how to refactor code like this. Let's say we have a function to create the image processing ops:

```
def process_image(file_name):
    file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
    ...
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
    return normalized
```

This is basically your `read_tensor_from_image_file` function except for the last part involving a session. What you currently do is basically

```
def label_image(file_name, ...):
    processed = process_image(file_name)
    sess = tf.Session()
    result = sess.run(processed)
    ....

for file_name in files:
    label_image(file_name, ...)
```

Instead, what you should do is

```
filename_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
processed = process_image(filename_placeholder)

def label_image(file_name, ...):
    result = sess.run(processed, feed_dict={filename_placeholder: file_name})
    ....

for file_name in files:
    label_image(file_name, ...)
```

The important difference is that we moved the `process_image` call out of the loop and only `run` it inside. Also we do not create a new session continuously. The global variables are a bit icky but you should get the idea.

The only thing I'm not sure about is whether you can use the session you got from `get_session(graph)` to run the `processed` tensor. If this doesn't work (i.e. crashes) then you will need to create a second session to run this stuff, however you should only do this *once* after you call `process_image`, not repeatedly inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a straight-forward path to solving the problem (despite my rather limited tf skills). :-)

Comment: Cool, I was in a bit of a hurry when I wrote the answer so I could extend it with an example of what I mean as well if needed.

Comment: To be honest, I am struggling a bit to implement the above, although I theoretically understand what needs to be fixed. If you could provide an example of the refactored label_image and read_tensor_from_image_file would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I edited it with an example, hope that is enough.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, indeed. When I follow your example, it throws the following error, though: _AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'endswith'_

Comment: Damn. Can you use `tf.image.decode_image ` instead? According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_image), this should detect the format automatically so we can avoid checking the file name ending.

Comment: That worked, but now I get: _ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", dtype=string) is not an element of this graph._ + _During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", dtype=string) is not an element of this graph._ haha, it's a misery. I think I need some one-on-one help here. Thanks for your effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-allocation is still possible. Read the size of the full file, then allocate memory for whatever object.

Where do you save files? If performance takes a dive during a loop it's usually indicative of accessing an ever-growing container.

Try writing all information in a pre-allocated array and then write all data entries at once in the *.csv, instead of opening the ever-growing *.csv file once every loop. This will fix the issue in this case. I'm assuming that `results = label_image(image, graph, session, input_height=299, input_width=299, input_layer="Mul")` does not open any container but works only on the input arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In fact, previously I used an array to store the data before writing it to a csv (without pre-allocation, so it also slowed down gradually). I will give it another try. However, I often lost all interim predictions when my computer crashed unlike the solution with the csv where each additional prediction is immediately stored.